# Help identifying mouse-like rodent in Tuscany (Italy)

Tags: animal-identification

I have seen this mouse in a wood on the Via Francigena, close to San Gimignano (Tuscany, in Italy).

I would like to know which kind of mouse/rodent it is.

The mouse was almost not moving, probably as a defensive strategy.

[image: mouse]

Comment: I am not familar with the mice species in Italy, but in the US we have many species that are difficult to tell apart without certain measurements (ear length, tail length, foot  length) that may vary if the individual is M/F or adult vs juvenile. And even then, there is some overlap. My guess would be a regular old house mouse, but again, ???

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a **wood mouse**, aka **field mouse**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wood_mouse) says

> The wood mouse (Apodemus sylvaticus) is a murid rodent native to Europe and northwestern Africa.
> . . .
> Wood mice inhabit forests, grasslands, and cultivated fields, tending to seek out more wooded areas in winter. Almost entirely nocturnal and terrestrial, wood mice burrow extensively, build nests of plants and live in buildings during harsh seasons.

This suggests it is unusual to see one during the day.

---

Why isn't it a **harvest mouse**?

Harvest mice are smaller than field/wood mice, and have a more reddish coat and smaller ears. This page
[House mouse or field mouse? Easy guide to types of UK mice, voles and shrews](https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/blog/2022/03/types-of-uk-mice/)
summaries the different types of mice found in UK, which probably applies across Europe.